# How to print off list of all products from Magento?

Tags: php, magento

Is there a way to print off all products and their categories in Magento or a way of calling all of this information from the db in a custom script easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all products :

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name');
foreach($products as $product){
    echo 'Name:'.$product->name.' sky:'.$product->sku.'<br>';    
}
```

You can add as many attributes as you want with `addAttributeToSelect('attribute_name')`